# How to extract name from id card picture

Tags: computer-vision, ocr

I'm studying how to get a person name from pictures of their id cards, considering their ids can have different layouts.

Using OCR services I'm able to read the text from the card, yet I'm not sure how to identify what is the person's name.

Using Microsoft Custom Vision I was able to train the service to identify what kind of ID card was posted, since I know all available cards I'll accept.

Is there a way to map each kind of card to an area, or transform to extract the area, in a way I can use OCR only on it? This way I can extract only the name.

OBS: I open to using any kind o service that facilitates this

Comment: show examples. If you are able to read the text, how comes you are not able to get the name?

Comment: identify the card layout, crop the name field and apply ocr. or read all words and discard everything that is not a name

Comment: I'm able to read the text but can't programmatically extract the name, how to differentiate the person name and the state name for example. To crop the image I need to map the layout to a transform that will give the area to crop. The image could be zoomed, tilted etc. I'm trying to figure out how to do this

Comment: Apparently what I'm looking for is called "zonal OCR", yet I couldn't find a service or library to integrate. This is probably not as simple as I imagined initially

Comment: have you got the answer?? coz i am working of similar project and i am not able to detect names...